# Add sqlsrv extension to php in xampp

Tags: php, xampp, sqlsrv

I want to connect to SQL Server with php. From my search, I gather that, if your platform is Windows you should use the sqlsrv extension and when it is Linux you should use dblib extension.

I want to use both of them, but in Windows I can't install sqlsrv.

I download php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll and put it in the ext directory in xampp and add following line to php.ini:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll
```

After that, I restart apache, but in phpinfo(), I can't access sqlsrv and I get the error below:

```
Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

How can I solve it?

My xampp version : 3.2.1
My php version : 5.5.3

Comment: Your php version is not compatible with the sqlsrv driver you have downloaded. There are only unofficial drivers for php 5.5.x, you can check it here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1d37219-88a3-46b2-a421-73bfa33fe433/unofficial-php-55-drivers-x86

Comment: totally worked. how did you find out that it was due to system variables????